# css id added through jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am adding table in html through jquery dynamically. I am able to add. But I can't remove added table. CSS 'remove' id which is appended from jquery doesn't work. 'remove' Id is added in section tag at last of script

Jquery

```
    $().ready(function(){
        $('#AddMoreId').on('click', function(){
                $('article:last').append('<article class="col100 left bggreen"><table><tr><th>ID</th><td><input type="number" id="id"></td></tr><tr><th>Menu in NPL</th><td><input type="text" id="menunep"></input></td></tr><tr><th>Menu in ENG</th><td><input type="text" id="menueng"></input></td></tr></table><section class="col100 left cursorpointer" id="remove">Remove</section></article><br/>');
        });

        $('#remove').on('click', function(){ 
            $(this).parents('article').remove();
        });

    });
```

Html

```
<article class="col100 left bggreen">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="id">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Menu in NPL
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="menunep"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Menu in ENG
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="menueng"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cursorpointer" colspan="2" id="AddMoreId">Add field
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following code.

1. you need change `id` to `class`
2. use `closest` instead of `parent`

```js
$().ready(function() {
        $('#AddMoreId').on('click', function(){
                $('article:last').append('<article class="col100 left bggreen"><table><tr><th>ID</th><td><input type="number" id="id"></td></tr><tr><th>Menu in NPL</th><td><input type="text" id="menunep"></input></td></tr><tr><th>Menu in ENG</th><td><input type="text" id="menueng"></input></td></tr></table><section class="col100 left cursorpointer remove1" >Remove</section></article><br/>');
        });

      $(document).on('click', '.remove1', function(){ 
       $(this).closest('article').remove();
     });

   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="col100 left bggreen">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="id">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Menu in NPL
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="menunep" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Menu in ENG
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="menueng" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cursorpointer" colspan="2" id="AddMoreId">Add field
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</article>
```

Comment: @patlarpan, Thanks This one works perfectly.

Comment: welcome @AnandHmt :). then you can upvote also

Comment: @paltarpan, I upvote right answer always. But sometimes instant upvote doesn't work after checking green tick.

Comment: Ok no problem @AnandHmt :)

Answer (score 3):

For dynamically added items, use the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#remove', function(){ 
    $(this).parents('article').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){ 
    $(this).parents('article').remove();
});
```

Also you should note that you will have multiple buttons with id "remove", which is considered invalid, you should change it to use class instead.

Comment: thanks for you information, In my case changing parents to closest works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the id is being generated dynamically. For this to work well, you need to modify the code as follows:

```
$('.bggreen').on('click', '#remove', function(){ 
    $(this).parents('article').remove();
});
```